# How to link google drive using google colab

Tags: python

I'm trying to read images to from google drive using google colab.Images are in folder AnomalyDetection/images

I'm trying to link the folder using following command

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

os.chdir("drive/My Drive/AnomalyDetection/images")
os.listdir()
```

But I'm getting error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive/My Drive/AnomalyDetection/images'
```

Can you suggest me the correct way to connect the google drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add content first.

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/AnomalyDetection/images")
os.listdir()
```